# Pot stick to induction top not able to remove it plz advice

Tags: food-safety

Kindly advice me how to remove pot stick on induction top while cooking curry .I have tried almost all ways but nothing worked, it's not moving(sliding or lifting up)

Comment: Do you mean that, wjile cooking curry, you had a pot is stuck to your stove top? Is it a result of food that dried on the underside (bottom) of your pot?

Comment: Does it seem food, or molten plastic, keeping the pot in place? What model induction top, what model pot?

Comment: If your pot bottom isn't flat and was wet, it could have suction cupped itself on...

Comment: Molten sugar can do the same thing ... or even over-heating enameled cast iron (but that requires a dry pan, as you have to get it hot enough to soften the enamel)

Comment: What material is it? Could it have been aluminium?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this happens to me frequently. In my case it was always a thin film of liquid (water) that was holding the pot to the glass. Don't try to lift it straight up - that would take the most force. Instead, grab both handles of the pot and twist.  If that doesn't work, you can try heating up the pot again and twist.